# Get urls from chromium's tabs using python 3

Tags: python, chromium, python-3.4

I'm trying to write a script in python 3 to take urls from chromium's tabs.
could someone tell me if there is any library that let me do that?
I searched on google and also here but I can't  found anything.
if there isn't nothing of that, could you tell me which is the fastest language to do this script?
(ps I'm working on debian).
thank you all

Comment: Could you describe more why do you need this and what is your end goal?

Comment: since normally I open about 20/30 tabs on chromium I would like to create a program that let me save all urls in a .txt file to let me close all tabs without losing these and let me open a new instance of chrome to navigate in other tabs (I would like do that to don't make slower the system)
With the same program I have to open all of these tabs (I'll use webbrowser library)

Comment: I think you may be looking for [Chromium PyAuto](http://floss.zoomquiet.io/data/20120706150852/index.html). I've never used it, but it was the first hit in the obvious Google search.

Comment: Meanwhile, why do you care about "the fastest language"?

Comment: thank you =) I'm looking for "the fastest language" because I'm determined on the speed of programs.